# Display a list of objects in asp.net view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display a list of objects in my asp.net view but it somehow isn't working.

**VIEW**

```
@model List<WCFasp.net.Models.ViewProject>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowSelectedView";
}

@ViewBag.sl

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)</p>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Check(List<WCF.Project> selectedprojectlist)
{
    List<ViewProject> selectedlist = new List<ViewProject>();

    foreach (var dir in selectedprojectlist)
    {
        if (dir.IsChecked == true)
        {
            selectedlist.Add(new ViewProject(dir.Name, dir.Path, dir.Size, dir.LastChange, dir.IsChecked));
        }
    }

    ViewBag.sl = selectedlist.Count;

    return View("ShowSelectedView", selectedlist);
}
```

The ViewBag.sl displays Model.Count from the Controller. The Counter works and tells me there are objects in the list but it wont display them.

Does someone see an error or has an alternative idea?

Comment: Show me controller action code. you might have not return Model from action

Comment: give us a clean question. it is very confusing. show the `controller` and `view` code separately.

Comment: Check if `<p>` tag rendered or not?

Comment: @anand Do you see an error in the way I try to display it? Is it the correct way of displaying lists? Do you know an other way? Isn't that clear and you can just ask for the Controller. jeez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
       <p>@item.Name</p>
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Model.Count works fine also without brackets. It now displays "item.Name" and not the actual object Name. So I thought of adding an @ in front of item but then it displays nothing again.

Comment: Works now :) Had some trouble with the list that I am receiving as parameter.

Comment: What?? OP's model is `List<T>` which has a property `Count` so `Model.Count` **does work** God only knows who up voted this completely wrong answer. @Mr.Jackson, Your should not accept this - its misleading to other users that you have signaled this wrong answer works - it has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke is right. Sorry about that and i have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: @anand - Which now does exactly the same thing as OP's original code was doing (and adding a `if(Model.Count > 0)` block is just pointless). You answer has absolutely nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: what if `Model` has no data

Comment: Its only ever necessary to test for `null`, and since OP is passing a new instance of `List<ViewProject>()` to the view, it can never be null anyway (just an empty collection) so even that is pointless in this case.

Comment: So your new answer is _you can do it a different way (using a `foreach` loop) but it will still give you exactly the same error as you were getting before_.

Comment: It will give exactly the same error as OP was initially getting. OP's issue was unrelated to the code he showed (as noted in the 4th comment) - it was caused by something else he did not show.Your answer has nothing at all to do with problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach.

```
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <div>@item.Name</div>
    }
```